# Access rules restriction in yii

Tags: php, yii, access-rules

In my account model, I have an attribute called account_type_id
upon registration if the user chooses his account to be an Admin account then it is set to 1 if however the user will be just an ordinary user it is set to 2
how do I change the access rules so that only the ones which are set to 1 can update or delete?

this is a sample of my code

```
 public function accessRules()
{
    $account=Account::model()->FindAll();
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'action'=>array('update', 'delete', 'admin'),
            'expression'=>"{$account->account_type_id}==1",
            ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: you want to add rule for new user type for update and delete?

Comment: What is your problem now?  {$account->account_type_id}==1 not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has one problem: Your `$account` is a array of objects, so you can't use `$account->account_type_id`. This has no meaning. User table should have a `account_type_id` field. So you can access the account_type_id of the logged in user anywhere in your application.
You can try this:

```
array('allow',
        'action'=>array('update', 'delete', 'admin'),
        'expression'=> array('AccessControl','allowAdminOnly'),
        ),
```

Then you need to define `AccessControl` class and `allowAdminOnly` function in that class. `AccessControl` could be anywhere, for example in your extensions folder. Note `allowAdminOnly` muse return true or false. `AccessControl` should be like this:

```
class AccessControl{

   public function allowAdminOnly()
   {
      if(Yii::app()->user->account_type_id == 1)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: just one question though, do I really need to transfer the account_type_id to the user table?

Comment: Yes, You should add that field to the user table and add reference from it to the user_id field.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to implement something like this [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system/) or this [one](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/474/implementing-a-flat-user-access-system/)

So your access rules looks something like this:

```
// for access rules
return array(
      array('allow', 
        'actions'=>array('update','delete','admin'),
        'expression'=>'$user->isAdmin()'
      ),
// ...
```